# How to exclude a field in a SQLite full text search (fts5)

Tags: sql, sqlite

To search across all fields to do a full text search in sqlite I can do:

```
SELECT * FROM investments_v ('facebook');
```

Is there a way to exclude one or more fields from this, for example, in pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM investments_v ('facebook') in all fields except 'url' and 'category'
```

How could that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#fts5_column_filters):

> If a column filter specification is preceded by a "-" character, then it is interpreted as a list of column not to match against.

So something like

```
SELECT *
FROM investmests_v
WHERE investments_v MATCH '-url:facebook';
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. Could you please show how to do that with multiple excluded fields and I'll accept the answer (just updated the question)

Comment: @David542 It's also in the documentation... `'-{url category}:facebook'`. You can also mark a column as [unindexed](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#the_unindexed_column_option) when creating the table to permanently exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do that, but the opposite way would be to include all fields except the included ones, for example

```
SELECT * FROM investments_v ('{company_country_code company_name}: "facebook"');
```